# Setting symbol rotation by attribute field with Python in QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, symbology

I'm making a plugin for QGIS that displays aircrafts in real time. This is how I am setting the symbol styles, but I don't know how to set the angle based on the heading of the airplane. I can do it manually (shown in photo) but I need a way to set this using Python in my plugin.
I change the position of each feature as it changes, is there a way I can change a feature rotation? Or is there a way to change the symbol style to set the angle by field attribute?

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
symbol = layer.renderer().symbol()

svgStyle = {}
svgStyle['fill'] = '#000000'
svgStyle['name'] = 'C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis/svg/transport/transport_airport.svg'
svgStyle['outline'] = '#000000'
svgStyle['outline-width'] = '0.3'
svgStyle['size'] = '7'

symbol_layer = QgsSvgMarkerSymbolLayer.create(svgStyle)
symbol.changeSymbolLayer(0, symbol_layer)
```

[image: Manually setting symbol rotation in QGIS]

Answer (score 2):

The property you're looking for is a method from `QgsMarkerSymbol` it's called [dataDefinedAngle()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Marker/QgsMarkerSymbol.html?highlight=qgsmarkersymbol#qgis.core.QgsMarkerSymbol.dataDefinedAngle), you can change it by using [setDataDefinedAngle()](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/Marker/QgsMarkerSymbol.html?highlight=qgsmarkersymbol#qgis.core.QgsMarkerSymbol.setDataDefinedAngle).
This method requires a `QgsProperty` based on a field. You need to create it with the method `fromField()`.

You just need to add this one line at the end of your snippet :

```
symbol.setDataDefinedAngle(QgsProperty().fromField("Heading"))
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!